# How can I get the code line number along with errorinfo?

Tags: tcl

I am using the following TCL code:

```
proc RunCSM { scen } {
                catch { $scen start }
                if { "[$scen status]" != "SUCCESS" } {
                        puts "$scen FAILED.  Error Info:"
                        puts "[$scen errorInfo]" ...
```

The problem is that in this case that there is an error, it shows the error info debug information as desired as the output of errorInfo flag, but in this case I need also the line number of the code that fails. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way, from 8.5 onwards, is to switch to the form of `catch` that lets you get the extended result information as a dictionary (in the `opt` variable below) in its *second* optional argument after the script:

```
catch { $scen start } msg opt
if { "[$scen status]" ne "SUCCESS" } {   # use 'ne' to compare strings, please
    set info [dict get $opt -errorinfo]
    set line [dict get $opt -errorline]
    puts "$scen FAILED saying '$msg' at $line. Error Info:"
    puts $info
    # ...
}
```

Comment: You could try parsing the errorinfo, but it's awkward with 8.4 (which is very out of date now and rather unsupported, BTW). We made it a lot easier to get in 8.5…